# Thermodynamic relation

Tags: thermodynamics, volume, chemical-potential

Can someone please explain the following thermodynamic relation to me?

$$\biggl ( \frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial N_2} \biggl )_{V,T,N'} = \biggl ( \frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial N_2} \biggl )_{P, T, N'} + \frac{\bar v_1 \bar v_2}{V \chi_T }$$
where $\mu_1$ is the chemical potential of the first component in a solution, $N_2$ is the amount of molecules of the second component in the solution, and  $\chi_T$ is the isothermal compressibility.

Thanks a lot.
Best regards.

Comment: What is N'?....

Comment: @Chemomechanics Hello, I found it in this article (appendix eq. A12): https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.481565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek $$\left( \frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial N_2} \right)_{V,T,N_1} = \left( \frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial N_2} \right)_{P, T, N_1} + \frac{\bar v_1 \bar v_2}{V \chi_T },\tag{1}$$
for a two-component system, where $\mu_i$ and $N_i$ are respectively the chemical potential and amount of component $i$; $V$, $T$, and $P$ are respectively the system volume, temperature, and pressure; $\bar v_i$ is the molar volume of component $i$, and $\chi_T$ is the isothermal compressibility.

(You and the [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.481565)'s authors write $N^\prime$ instead of $N_1$, but $N^\prime$ in this context is the vector of $N_i$ terms other than that being differentiated, which in the two-component case is simply $N_1$ for this equation.)

Let us write $d\mu_1$ in terms of the three variables $T$, $N_2$, and $P$:

$$d\mu_1=\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dT}\right)_{N_2,P}dT+\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dN_2}\right)_{T,P}dN_2+\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dP}\right)_{T,N_2}dP.$$

Differentiate with respect to $N_2$ while keeping  $T$ and $V$ constant, and then stipulate that $N_1$ is constant:

$$\left(\frac{d\mu_1}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,V,N_1}=\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dN_2}\right)_{T,P,N_1}+\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dP}\right)_{T,N_1,N_2}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,V,N_1}.\tag{2}$$

(Various things are happening in this step. First, as always, we apply the chain rule when differentiating products, but we then drop differential terms as relatively minuscule, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial N_2}\left[\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dP}dP\right]=\frac{\partial^2 \mu_1}{dP\,dN_2}dP+\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dP}\right)\left(\frac{\partial P}{dN_2}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{dP}\right)\left(\frac{\partial P}{dN_2}\right)$. Second, the assumption of constant $T$ means that any term multiplied by $dT$ disappears. Third, $\frac{\partial N_2}{\partial N_2}=1$. In the end, therefore, only the differential terms are modified: the first—$dT$—disappears, the second—$dN_2$—turns to 1, and the third—$dP$—is differentiated under the constraints.)

Note that the partial molar volumes are

$$\bar v_1\equiv\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_1}\right)_{T,P,N_2}=\left(\frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N_1,N_2};\tag{3}$$$$\bar v_2\equiv\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,P,N_1},$$
where a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations) was applied.

It will also be useful to write a [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) in the form of

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,V,N_1}\left(\frac{\partial N_2}{\partial V}\right)_{T,P,N_1}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N_1,N_2}=-1,$$

or

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial N_2}\right)_{T,V,N_1}=\frac{\bar v_2}{V\kappa_T},\tag{4}$$

where the isothermal compressibility $\kappa_T$ is defined as

$$\kappa_T\equiv-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N_1,N_2}.$$

By substitution of (3) and (4) into (2), this should all come together to give (1), the expression we seek. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot! This really helped. I'm not sure, how you got eq 2. But I'll find out. This solution looks great.

Comment: You're welcome! I added an summary of what happens to get to Eq. 2. Hope this clarifies.