# Why is the partial molar volume of interest?

Tags: applied-physics

I have to present a technique for calculation of the partial molar volume of molecules (using the 3D reference interaction site model). I'm trying to find some possible applications for the partial molar volume of (macro)molecules for this presentation.

Does anyone know any?

Comment: Hopefully, this is a useful starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_molar_property

Answer (score 1):

In addition to its literal relevance regarding the increase in volume $V$ from adding component $i$ (all else fixed), I noticed when writing a [recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609250/thermodynamic-relation/609352#609352) that the partial molar volume $\bar v_i$ also provides the change in the chemical potential $\mu_i$ of that component with changes in pressure $P$ in a closed system: $$\bar v_1\equiv\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_i}\right)_{T,P,N^\prime}=\left(\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial P}\right)_{T,N_i},$$

where $N_i$ is the amount of component $i$, $T$ is temperature, and $N^\prime$ is a list of the amounts of all components not including component $i$ (sometimes written $_{N_j\neq N_i}$). This can be obtained via a Maxwell relation.

Answer (score 0):

So far I came across the following applications:

1. three-dimensional structure determination by protein crystallography
2. studies of macromolecular oligomers in aqueous environment
3. analysis of the pressure effect on chemical reactions
4. solutions in general (for example water and ethanol)

Sources:
https://dx.doi.org/10.1110%2Fps.04688204

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_molar_property

https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1600437

http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/118699/06-Imai.pdf?sequence=1

This was quite interesting, too:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-use-of-finding-the-partial-molar-volumes-of-solutes-in-different-solutions